# Dotnetnuke clone a tab using parent tab

Tags: dotnetnuke

I need to clone a dnn tab programmatically from my asp.net application. Currently it will create a new tab with parent content/permission.but in my parent page there are many sub pages available.how i can create a new page with all those sub pages in programmatically

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a programmatic way to handle this directly as far as I know.  You would need to from that parent tab enumerate the children and add those just like how you added the parent copy.